# What is happening under the hood of fasttext supervised learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, fasttext

We can train a supervised model in fasttext using

```
import fasttext
model = fasttext.train_supervised(input="cooking.train")
```

My question is how it is representing the features(Bag of words or tf/idf or word embedding) and what algorithm is it using for text classification?

Comment: It is really `under the hood` - but `under the food` really made my day :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still learning word-vectors for the input text - but then averaging them all together, a bit like an infinite-window CBOW mode – then using that to predict the the labels, as if the labels were the (word2vec-style) predicted-word.

Comment: Thanks @gojomo. What algorithm is it using for text classification?

Comment: As a shallow neural network, it's very similar to a perceptron, though perhaps there's a more specific name (other than 'fasttext') that eludes me, for its exact mixture of summed-projection-vectors & negative-sampling or hierarchical-softmax output layer.